# How to stop a background thread on keyboard flip in android

Tags: android, multithreading

How can I stop a background thread on keyboard flip in android?

Comment: How about some details, code sample, etc?

Comment: I would like to either wait for a background thread execution to finish before activity is recreated on keyboard slide in/out or kill the thread itself so that i can start the thread afresh on orientation change.

For example:
If you search for a word in the android market application and scroll down, flip the keyboard while the files are being loaded, notice that the layout does not change until the results are displayed.

I want to achieve similar behavior.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When the keyboard flip occurs, the current activity is killed and restarted in the new orientation.  So I would imagine you would want to stop the thread on the `onPause()` or `onDestroy()` method.

The following StackOverflow question might be relevant: [Activity restart on rotation Android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/456211/activity-restart-on-rotation-android)